# выставить порядковый номер новой колонки в скрипте миграции Liquibase

Tags: sql, postgresql, миграция, liquibase

я добавляю в таблицу новые колонки.

```
alter table manual_security add isin_code varchar(12) not null;
alter table manual_security add sec_subtype varchar(12) not null;
alter table manual_security add security_id integer primary key not null;
```

на скриншоте видно, что они последовательно добавляются внизу списка колонок в таблице.
а мне нужно чтобы isin_code был первым в списке. это можно как-то задать в скрипте миграции?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Принимаете мысль, что порядок полей не имеет значения. Ну либо удаляете таблицу, создаёте новую с новым порядком полей.

В postgresql нет возможности менять порядок хранения полей.